# Replace word(s) before or after certain strings

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file containing 500+ lines of text. On each line there will be a portion that begins with `<p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong>`, then has a list of "classes" such as `Artificer, Bard, Wizard` or `Druid, Ranger`, and ends with `</p>`.

My goal is to replace each class with a special link I use for a program of mine. The link will look something like `@UUID[uniqueID]{className}`.

Normally I'd use Find and Replace in Notepad++ for each class name, but the class names show up in other parts of the document that I don't want to erase, so I need to replace the ones located specifically within the context I listed above. I'm sure I can do this with RegEx but I've never used it before so I have no idea how to do this correctly. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Example input:

```
{"name":"Pyrotechnics","type":"spell","img":"icons/magic/fire/beam-jet-stream-embers.webp","effects":[],"folder":null,"sort":0,"flags":{"betterRolls5e":{"critRange":{"type":"String","value":null},"critDamage":{"type":"String","value":""},"quickDesc":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickAttack":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickSave":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickDamage":{"type":"Array","value":[],"altValue":[],"context":[]},"quickVersatile":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false},"quickProperties":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickCharges":{"type":"Boolean","value":{"use":true,"resource":true},"altValue":{"use":true,"resource":true}},"quickTemplate":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickOther":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true,"context":""},"quickFlavor":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickPrompt":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false}},"core":{"sourceId":"Item.yrc5woADzAc984yq"}},"_id":"0BSwV45mHGYEPMru","system":{"description":{"value":"<p>Choose an area of flame that you can see and that can fit within a 5-foot cube within range. You can extinguish the fire in that area, and you create either fireworks or smoke.</p><p><strong>Fireworks.</strong> The target explodes with a dazzling display of colors. Each creature within 10 feet of the target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or become blinded until the end of your next turn.</p><p><strong>Smoke.</strong> Thick black smoke spreads out from the target in a 20-foot radius, moving around corners. The area of the smoke is heavily obscured. The smoke persists for 1 minute or until a strong wind disperses it.</p><p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong> Sorcerer, Wizard, Artificer</p>","chat":"","unidentified":""},"source":"XGE","activation":{"type":"action","cost":1,"condition":""},"duration":{"value":null,"units":"inst"},"target":{"value":5,"width":null,"units":"ft","type":"cube"},"range":{"value":60,"long":null,"units":"ft"},"uses":{"value":0,"max":"0","per":"","recovery":""},"consume":{"type":"","target":"","amount":null},"ability":"","actionType":"save","attackBonus":0,"chatFlavor":"","critical":{"threshold":null,"damage":null},"damage":{"parts":[],"versatile":""},"formula":"","save":{"ability":"con","dc":null,"scaling":"spell"},"level":2,"school":"trs","components":{"value":"","vocal":true,"somatic":true,"material":false,"ritual":false,"concentration":false},"materials":{"value":"","consumed":false,"cost":0,"supply":0},"preparation":{"mode":"prepared","prepared":false},"scaling":{"mode":"none","formula":""}},"ownership":{"default":0,"LCw1mxC8S2Al3dWA":3},"_stats":{"systemId":"dnd5e","systemVersion":"2.0.3","coreVersion":"10.286","createdTime":null,"modifiedTime":1664781982673,"lastModifiedBy":"UjfixXuqstXNdypa"}}
{"_id":"0QjwfM5ugpGCZIDV","name":"Resistance","type":"spell","img":"icons/magic/defensive/shield-barrier-blue.webp","effects":[],"folder":null,"sort":0,"flags":{"core":{"sourceId":"Compendium.world.spells-expanded.dl8YwvMboBqX2OC4"},"mre-dnd5e":{"formulaGroups":[{"label":"Primary","formulaSet":[]}]},"rest-recovery":{"data":{"recovery":{"enabled":false}}}},"system":{"description":{"value":"<p>You touch one willing creature. Once before the spell ends, the target can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to one saving throw of its choice. It can roll the die before or after making the saving throw. The spell then ends.</p><p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong>Cleric, Druid</p>","chat":"","unidentified":""},"source":"PHB","activation":{"type":"action","cost":1,"condition":""},"duration":{"value":1,"units":"minute"},"target":{"value":1,"width":null,"units":"","type":"creature"},"range":{"value":null,"long":null,"units":"touch"},"uses":{"value":0,"max":"0","per":"","recovery":""},"consume":{"type":"","target":"","amount":null},"ability":"","actionType":"util","attackBonus":0,"chatFlavor":"","critical":{"threshold":null,"damage":null},"damage":{"parts":[],"versatile":"","value":""},"formula":"1d4","save":{"ability":"","dc":null,"scaling":"spell","value":""},"level":0,"school":"abj","components":{"value":"","vocal":true,"somatic":true,"material":true,"ritual":false,"concentration":true},"materials":{"value":"A miniature clock","consumed":false,"cost":0,"supply":0},"preparation":{"mode":"prepared","prepared":false},"scaling":{"mode":"none","formula":""}},"ownership":{"default":0,"LCw1mxC8S2Al3dWA":3},"_stats":{"systemId":"dnd5e","systemVersion":"2.0.3","coreVersion":"10.288","createdTime":null,"modifiedTime":1668307772539,"lastModifiedBy":"EHpONhziSoZpUpN3"}}
{"_id":"0WqAKsgwfM272Ugk","name":"Elemental Bane","type":"spell","img":"icons/skills/melee/shield-damaged-broken-gold.webp","effects":[],"folder":null,"sort":0,"flags":{"betterRolls5e":{"critRange":{"type":"String","value":null},"critDamage":{"type":"String","value":""},"quickDesc":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickAttack":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickSave":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickDamage":{"type":"Array","value":[],"altValue":[],"context":[]},"quickVersatile":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false},"quickProperties":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickCharges":{"type":"Boolean","value":{"use":true,"resource":true},"altValue":{"use":true,"resource":true}},"quickTemplate":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickOther":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true,"context":""},"quickFlavor":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickPrompt":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false}},"core":{"sourceId":"Item.VsKT5bvnBuMZpsqp"},"mre-dnd5e":{"formulaGroups":[{"label":"Primary","formulaSet":[]}]}},"system":{"description":{"value":"<p>Choose one creature you can see within range, and choose one of the following damage types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, or thunder. The target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or be affected by the spell for its duration. The first time each turn the affected target takes damage of the chosen type, the target takes an extra 2d6 damage of that type. Moreover, the target loses any resistance to that damage type until the spell ends.</p>\n<p><strong>At Higher Levels.</strong> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 5th level or higher, you can target one additional creature for each slot level above 4th. The creatures must be within 30 feet of each other when you target them.</p>\n<p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong> Warlock, Wizard, Artificer</p>","chat":"","unidentified":""},"source":"XGE","activation":{"type":"action","cost":1,"condition":""},"duration":{"value":1,"units":"minute"},"target":{"value":1,"width":null,"units":"","type":"creature"},"range":{"value":90,"long":null,"units":"ft"},"uses":{"value":0,"max":"0","per":"","recovery":""},"consume":{"type":"","target":"","amount":null},"ability":"","actionType":"save","attackBonus":0,"chatFlavor":"","critical":{"threshold":null,"damage":null},"damage":{"parts":[],"versatile":""},"formula":"","save":{"ability":"con","dc":null,"scaling":"spell"},"level":4,"school":"trs","components":{"value":"","vocal":true,"somatic":true,"material":false,"ritual":false,"concentration":true},"materials":{"value":"","consumed":false,"cost":0,"supply":0},"preparation":{"mode":"prepared","prepared":false},"scaling":{"mode":"none","formula":""}},"ownership":{"default":0,"LCw1mxC8S2Al3dWA":3},"_stats":{"systemId":"dnd5e","systemVersion":"2.0.3","coreVersion":"10.286","createdTime":null,"modifiedTime":1664757812337,"lastModifiedBy":"WaZ5phMRyaHwTSEz"}}
```

Desired output:

```
{"name":"Pyrotechnics","type":"spell","img":"icons/magic/fire/beam-jet-stream-embers.webp","effects":[],"folder":null,"sort":0,"flags":{"betterRolls5e":{"critRange":{"type":"String","value":null},"critDamage":{"type":"String","value":""},"quickDesc":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickAttack":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickSave":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickDamage":{"type":"Array","value":[],"altValue":[],"context":[]},"quickVersatile":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false},"quickProperties":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickCharges":{"type":"Boolean","value":{"use":true,"resource":true},"altValue":{"use":true,"resource":true}},"quickTemplate":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickOther":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true,"context":""},"quickFlavor":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickPrompt":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false}},"core":{"sourceId":"Item.yrc5woADzAc984yq"}},"_id":"0BSwV45mHGYEPMru","system":{"description":{"value":"<p>Choose an area of flame that you can see and that can fit within a 5-foot cube within range. You can extinguish the fire in that area, and you create either fireworks or smoke.</p><p><strong>Fireworks.</strong> The target explodes with a dazzling display of colors. Each creature within 10 feet of the target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or become blinded until the end of your next turn.</p><p><strong>Smoke.</strong> Thick black smoke spreads out from the target in a 20-foot radius, moving around corners. The area of the smoke is heavily obscured. The smoke persists for 1 minute or until a strong wind disperses it.</p><p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong>@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.NX28XQnco4pjOzF6]{Sorcerer}@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.5YX3k6END6NQWHOB]{Wizard}@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.3wFSjqwXndAQ8P2i]{Artificer}</p>","chat":"","unidentified":""},"source":"XGE","activation":{"type":"action","cost":1,"condition":""},"duration":{"value":null,"units":"inst"},"target":{"value":5,"width":null,"units":"ft","type":"cube"},"range":{"value":60,"long":null,"units":"ft"},"uses":{"value":0,"max":"0","per":"","recovery":""},"consume":{"type":"","target":"","amount":null},"ability":"","actionType":"save","attackBonus":0,"chatFlavor":"","critical":{"threshold":null,"damage":null},"damage":{"parts":[],"versatile":""},"formula":"","save":{"ability":"con","dc":null,"scaling":"spell"},"level":2,"school":"trs","components":{"value":"","vocal":true,"somatic":true,"material":false,"ritual":false,"concentration":false},"materials":{"value":"","consumed":false,"cost":0,"supply":0},"preparation":{"mode":"prepared","prepared":false},"scaling":{"mode":"none","formula":""}},"ownership":{"default":0,"LCw1mxC8S2Al3dWA":3},"_stats":{"systemId":"dnd5e","systemVersion":"2.0.3","coreVersion":"10.286","createdTime":null,"modifiedTime":1664781982673,"lastModifiedBy":"UjfixXuqstXNdypa"}}
{"_id":"0QjwfM5ugpGCZIDV","name":"Resistance","type":"spell","img":"icons/magic/defensive/shield-barrier-blue.webp","effects":[],"folder":null,"sort":0,"flags":{"core":{"sourceId":"Compendium.world.spells-expanded.dl8YwvMboBqX2OC4"},"mre-dnd5e":{"formulaGroups":[{"label":"Primary","formulaSet":[]}]},"rest-recovery":{"data":{"recovery":{"enabled":false}}}},"system":{"description":{"value":"<p>You touch one willing creature. Once before the spell ends, the target can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to one saving throw of its choice. It can roll the die before or after making the saving throw. The spell then ends.</p><p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong>@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.G7cm1ctzhtxEOvxS]{Cleric}@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.1IHQ3bZ4aCi15dlH]{Druid}</p>","chat":"","unidentified":""},"source":"PHB","activation":{"type":"action","cost":1,"condition":""},"duration":{"value":1,"units":"minute"},"target":{"value":1,"width":null,"units":"","type":"creature"},"range":{"value":null,"long":null,"units":"touch"},"uses":{"value":0,"max":"0","per":"","recovery":""},"consume":{"type":"","target":"","amount":null},"ability":"","actionType":"util","attackBonus":0,"chatFlavor":"","critical":{"threshold":null,"damage":null},"damage":{"parts":[],"versatile":"","value":""},"formula":"1d4","save":{"ability":"","dc":null,"scaling":"spell","value":""},"level":0,"school":"abj","components":{"value":"","vocal":true,"somatic":true,"material":true,"ritual":false,"concentration":true},"materials":{"value":"A miniature clock","consumed":false,"cost":0,"supply":0},"preparation":{"mode":"prepared","prepared":false},"scaling":{"mode":"none","formula":""}},"ownership":{"default":0,"LCw1mxC8S2Al3dWA":3},"_stats":{"systemId":"dnd5e","systemVersion":"2.0.3","coreVersion":"10.288","createdTime":null,"modifiedTime":1668307772539,"lastModifiedBy":"EHpONhziSoZpUpN3"}}
{"_id":"0WqAKsgwfM272Ugk","name":"Elemental Bane","type":"spell","img":"icons/skills/melee/shield-damaged-broken-gold.webp","effects":[],"folder":null,"sort":0,"flags":{"betterRolls5e":{"critRange":{"type":"String","value":null},"critDamage":{"type":"String","value":""},"quickDesc":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickAttack":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickSave":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickDamage":{"type":"Array","value":[],"altValue":[],"context":[]},"quickVersatile":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false},"quickProperties":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickCharges":{"type":"Boolean","value":{"use":true,"resource":true},"altValue":{"use":true,"resource":true}},"quickTemplate":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickOther":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true,"context":""},"quickFlavor":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"altValue":true},"quickPrompt":{"type":"Boolean","value":false,"altValue":false}},"core":{"sourceId":"Item.VsKT5bvnBuMZpsqp"},"mre-dnd5e":{"formulaGroups":[{"label":"Primary","formulaSet":[]}]}},"system":{"description":{"value":"<p>Choose one creature you can see within range, and choose one of the following damage types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, or thunder. The target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or be affected by the spell for its duration. The first time each turn the affected target takes damage of the chosen type, the target takes an extra 2d6 damage of that type. Moreover, the target loses any resistance to that damage type until the spell ends.</p>\n<p><strong>At Higher Levels.</strong> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 5th level or higher, you can target one additional creature for each slot level above 4th. The creatures must be within 30 feet of each other when you target them.</p>\n<p><strong>Spell Lists.</strong>@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.JsbrmCx9VF1Sizn8]{Warlock}@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.5YX3k6END6NQWHOB]{Wizard}@UUID[Compendium.5e-complete.5e-journals.7iH4qANs2gxn0MIs.JournalEntryPage.3wFSjqwXndAQ8P2i]{Artificer}</p>","chat":"","unidentified":""},"source":"XGE","activation":{"type":"action","cost":1,"condition":""},"duration":{"value":1,"units":"minute"},"target":{"value":1,"width":null,"units":"","type":"creature"},"range":{"value":90,"long":null,"units":"ft"},"uses":{"value":0,"max":"0","per":"","recovery":""},"consume":{"type":"","target":"","amount":null},"ability":"","actionType":"save","attackBonus":0,"chatFlavor":"","critical":{"threshold":null,"damage":null},"damage":{"parts":[],"versatile":""},"formula":"","save":{"ability":"con","dc":null,"scaling":"spell"},"level":4,"school":"trs","components":{"value":"","vocal":true,"somatic":true,"material":false,"ritual":false,"concentration":true},"materials":{"value":"","consumed":false,"cost":0,"supply":0},"preparation":{"mode":"prepared","prepared":false},"scaling":{"mode":"none","formula":""}},"ownership":{"default":0,"LCw1mxC8S2Al3dWA":3},"_stats":{"systemId":"dnd5e","systemVersion":"2.0.3","coreVersion":"10.286","createdTime":null,"modifiedTime":1664757812337,"lastModifiedBy":"WaZ5phMRyaHwTSEz"}}
```

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1754711/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: Without an example of the input and output it is hard to say what exact regular expression you would need. I recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for reference and expression testing. Note that regex is a natural language processor and should be used carefully with parsed languages such as HTML. It could introduce unexpected errors in your document.

Comment: That's fair, I was trying to avoid that cause each line is long. But I went ahead and added a few lines.

Comment: OK for input text, but, what is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, been sick the past few days and have been out of it and therefore unhelpful lol. Input and output added to the post. Might be hard to see but you'll see the changes in each line directly after "<strong>Spell Lists.</strong>".